# Argument list too long. Building Hubbub HTML Parsing Library. execv

Tags: c, bash, makefile, xargs

When I attempt to build this library on my system (Fedora)

```
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.33.8-149.fc13.i686 #1 SMP Tue Aug 17 22:45:56 UTC 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

I get a long list of errors of which this is the last few lines:

```
build/makefiles/Makefile.top:542: warning: overriding commands for target `build-Linux-Linux-release-lib-static/src_charset_detect.o'
build/makefiles/Makefile.top:542: warning: ignoring old commands for target `build-Linux-Linux-release-lib-static/src_charset_detect.o'
 COMPILE: src/hubbub.c
cc: error trying to exec '/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.4/cc1': execv: Argument list too long
make: *** [build-Linux-Linux-release-lib-static/src_hubbub.o] Error 1
```

You can download the makefile this error appears to be in here:

```
http://www.touspassagers.org/downloadable/Makefile.top
```

I think I just need to break up the arguments to execv so there aren't so many.  How do I do this in the context of this file in each instance in which it appears?  I hear xargs is the way to go; but I don't know how to use it.  I'm pretty new to bash.

Comment: `cc1` is the compiler proper, the part that actually does the compiling (i.e. the stage after preprocessing, but the stage before assembling). It seems like your tool chain is providing too many command line options to the compiler proper (more than your operating system allows), which is rather weird and doesn't sound right. You can check the maximum number of arguments by looking for `ARG_MAX` in `<limits.h>`. POSIX says that at least 4096 characters must be supported, if your operating system has this same limit and you provide more than this to `execv`, it will fail.

Comment: Actually, after double-checking, it appears that `ARG_MAX` accounts for the total number of bytes for arguments *and* the environment variables. `execv` may return `E2BIG` if *"The number of bytes used by the new process image's argument list and environment list is greater than the system-imposed limit of {`ARG_MAX`} bytes."*

Comment: Whoop, thanks.  I changed it to the valid URL.

Comment: I read about ARG_MAX, that's what leads me to the conclusion that xargs is the solution.  I just don't know how to implement it :(

Comment: @akellehe: `xargs` won't help, because you can't split the arguments up, they must all be given to the compiler proper at the same time, otherwise they won't all be in effect for the translation unit.

Comment: Aww...  Would this be an appropriate time to submit a bug to the developers of the package?

Comment: @akellehe: Yeah, perhaps that's a good idea. I'm not sure what they can do to fix it other than to use less flags or less environment variables.

Comment: @dreamlax: If you put your comment in the form of an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: It's a shame that this Makefile defaults to suppressing the actual command line.  @akellehe: if this is still relevant six months later, could you please try "`make Q= VQ=`" (yes, equals signs with nothing after them, and make sure there's a space between `Q=` and `VQ=`) and edit the resulting output into your question?  That will make it show what it actually tried to do instead of just saying "COMPILE src/hubbub.c" which is useless.

Answer (score 0):

Try again after upgrading gcc to at least 4.5.0

I think this bug was [fixed](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=45157) in that release.

Comment: That doesn't appear to be quite the same thing - that's talking about response files (which are probably not in use here, although there's no way to tell) and `collect2` (which is a helper program used only at link time).

Answer (score 0):

On the basis of dreamlax's finding that the environment list also matters, you can check the environment prior to starting the build process and remove excessively long variables, or even try **env -i** *build-command*.